# Is event control iff in systemverilog the same like clock gating?

Tags: system-verilog

I have found like this code.

```
Always @(posedge clk iff rst==0 or posedge rst)
```

I think above code like clock gating code.
As I know , when rst is 1 then this block is never triggered.
So in other word, if I make rst 0 then the block is working.

But I'm not sure why this schme is introduced in here?

Answer (score 2):

`iff` is an event qualifier. It doesn't matter what the event left of the `iff` (edge or value change).

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 9.4.2.3 *Conditional event controls*:

> The @ event control can have an iff qualifier.
>
> ```
> module latch (output logic [31:0] y, input [31:0] a, input enable);
> always @(a iff enable == 1)
> y <= a; //latch is in transparent mode
> endmodule
> ```
>
> The event expression only triggers if the expression after the `iff` is true (as defined in 12.4), in this case when `enable` is equal to 1. This type of expression is evaluated when a changes and not when `enable` changes. Also, in similar event expressions of this type, `iff` has precedence over or. This can be made clearer by the use of parentheses.

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) suggests that `iff` could be synthesizable 9.2.2.4 *Sequential logic always_ff procedure*, however it is currently uncommon for a synthesizer to support `iff`. Therefore, it is not recommended to use `iff` in coded intended to be synthesized. There an semi-exception I mention below using `` `ifdef ``/`` `ifndef ``.

If it becomes synthesizable, `iff` could be used for clock, but it sill may not be the recommenced approach. Clock gating should be used for gating the clock of a large module that need to be dynamically suspended or turned off/on; not for handful of flops. Clock gating is rarely beneficial for small edge trigger designs. Typically using an enable pin or Q to D feedback is sufficient power/area savings.

---

A place where `iff` is helpful in RTL is with the classic scheduling issue with overlapping asynchronous set/reset. When `rst_n` and `set_n` are both low, reset (in the below example) has priority. If `rst_n` were to go high with `set_n` renaming low (no transition), a real flop would asynchronous set, but RTL will do nothing.

```
alway_ff @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n, negedge set_n) begin
  if (!rst_n) begin
     // ...
  end
  else if (!set_n) begin
     // ...
  end
  else begin
     // ...
  end
end
```

Adding `posedge rst_n iff !set_n` to the sensitivity list allows the corner case condition to function property. Since `iff` is not [currently] synthesizable, an `` `ifndef  `endif `` needs to be warped around it

```
alway_ff @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n, 
    `ifndef SYNTHESIS
      posedge rst_n iff !set_n,
    `endif
    negedge set_n) begin
  // ...
end
```

Comment: Did you mean that it is currently "recommended not to use iff in code intended to be synthesized"? You have written "recommended to to use iff ..." ? I tried to edit the answer because I believe that was your intention, but my edit was rejected.

Comment: @cojomojo I see the typo and will correct it. As far as I know `iff` is not supported by synthesis, but that could change.